# Ubuntu 12.10 64b does not shutdown

Tags: 12.10, drivers, ati, 64-bit, shutdown

I am a new linux user so i am not familiar with what actually is needed to check.
When shutting down or  trying to restart i get a screen with yellow letters and the system does not close or restart. I have to shut down manually. I can't type all the numbers but i will give the last ones. [90102.232650] [  end-trace 435966f5b367871  ] this seems to have happened after i downgraded the xorg so i can get drivers for my ATI card (Radeon HD 4850). The suspend command works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I also have an ATI Card. I found that it you install / update the driver and then run the following command in terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

After that has run then shutdown using:

```
sudo init0
```

Then restart your computer and try to shutdown the normal way.

Comment: The second command it said it does not exist

Comment: sorry it should of been `sudo init 0` but just restart it via your power button or something, if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I downgraded the Xorg to install the driver for my ati card, I uninstalled the driver because it didn't shutdown anymore, after that I upgraded and updated and the video appears as Gallium 0.4 on ATI RS780MN. now it makes a faster shutdown.
I hope this can help in any way..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the way you downgraded xorg was wrong.

I know the problem with drivers for Radeon HD 4xxx series. Remove your driver and install as usual. After that try this way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/fglrx
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy
```

Restart your computer.

This repository provides AMD Catalyst drivers for legacy graphics Radeon HD 2xxx - 4xxx for Ubuntu:

- 12.04 Precise Pangolin
- 12.10 Quantal Quetzal